# The Pillow package is required to use this function. error occurred. Help me

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I made a simple example of taking a screenshot.
I debugged this, but there was an error.

cord

```
import pyautogui
import PIL

pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

error

```
The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

I've already set up a pillow and version is 9.2.0(lastest version)
I'm using python 3.9.12
My Python version is compatible with the Pillow version.

I tried Pip install fill, pip install fill --upgrade, and so on
But it hasn't been fixed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (9.2.0)
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Can you call any functions in `PIL`  module or it returns error ?? Also please provide the command you used to install the pillow package

Comment: PIL fails to function and causes errors.
When downloading PIL, I used conda install -canaconda fillow.

Comment: **conda install pillow** doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed everything new and it's fixed!

Comment: Congrats! Well you should mark your answer correct and close the question 

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work perfectly on my side.

```
import pyautogui

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'D:\\image.png')
```

[image]

Comment: "PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function."
It does not run with an error.
Thank you for your answer...